# Ember.Route, why params not allowing props other than segmentation id?

Tags: ember.js

Why the model params is not allowing the extra params other than the segmentation id?

The route

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("users");
  this.route("userdetails", { path: "users/:user_id"});
}


Route is:
....

model: function(params) {
var user_status = params.user_status;
  console.log(user_status);
   return params;
}
serialize : function(model) {
   return { user_id: model.user_id, user_status : model.user_status }
 }
```

The users status is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` object of the `model` hook corresponds to the URL of the route. So here it corresponds to `/users/1` for a user_id of 1.

Ember grabs the `user_id` = 1, from this URL of the route and passes it as a parameter to the `model` hook.

Since there is no `user_status` in the URL, it's logging as `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

@Darshan Sawardekar answer is quite correct, but I would like to add that what you need to do is adding the missing dynamic segment in your route definition so that it can be accessed in the `serialize` hook.

```
  this.route("userdetails", { path: "users/:user_id/:user_status"});
```

Now doing:

```
serialize: function(model) {
  return { user_id: model.user_id, user_status : model.user_status };
}
```

should yield the correct params and the url should be something like:

```
/users/1/online
```

`online` is of course invented since I don't know what you user statuses would be.
See [here](http://jsbin.com/awibaj/5/edit) for a pseudo implementation (check the console log).

Hope it helps.